# Flutter: Check if multiple strings are empty or null while adding to array

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, null, dart-null-safety

Still learning flutter, but have what I think is a pretty simple question. I have two strings, one being a list defined in the widget state.

```
List<String> uploadedFileUrls1;
String uploadedFileUrl2;
```

Each string is then either populated with uploaded media (images or video). These are then used to update a record in Firebase using `arrayUnion` as shown.

```
final postsUpdateData = {
  ...createPostsRecordData()
//this is where I need to check if empty or null
   'postAssets': FieldValue.arrayUnion(uploadedFileUrls1 + [uploadedFileUrl2]),
 };
await columnPostsRecord.reference.update(postsUpdateData);
```

My question is, how do you check if either `string` is empty or null independent of each other and not write to the database for that particular string. It is currently writing an empty string and I need it to do nothing, not even write a null, if the string is empty. But if one string is populated, I need it to add that one to the array but nothing for the empty one. Is setting new variables the only way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `String.length` and `List.length` method to check if either of the string is empty! So your code would look something like this:

```dart
 List<String> uploadedFileUrls1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
 String uploadedFileUrl2 = '';

  if (uploadedFileUrls1.length != 0 && uploadedFileUrl2.length != 0) {
    print('both has data');
    // process your update
  } else {
    print('no data');
    // notify user or do something 
  }
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this would only check if either string is populated or not. The problem I am running into is I need to check if either string is empty independent of each other. For example, if `uploadedFileUrls1` is populated, but `uploadedFileUrl2` is not, I need the first to add to the `array` while the second does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
'postAssets': (FieldValue.arrayUnion(uploadedFileUrls1.removeWhere((item) => ["", null].contains(item)).toList() + [uploadedFileUrl2])),
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it is giving the following error `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.` for the `removeWhere` function.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Still running into issues, now with this error on the `toList` call: `The method 'toList' isn't defined for the type 'FieldValue'.`

Comment: Sorry there wasa mistake in the bracket. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best approach, but this was the only way I could figure out how to check each independently, and then update the array accordingly. This code is working as desired.

```
if (uploadedFileUrls1 !=null && uploadedFileUrl2 !=null)
'postAssets':FieldValue.arrayUnion(uploadedFileUrls1.whereNotNull().toList() + [uploadedFileUrl2].whereNotNull().toList()),

if (uploadedFileUrls1 !=null && uploadedFileUrl2 == null)
'postAssets':FieldValue.arrayUnion(uploadedFileUrls1.whereNotNull().toList()),

if (uploadedFileUrls1 ==null && uploadedFileUrl2 != null)
'postAssets':FieldValue.arrayUnion([uploadedFileUrl2].whereNotNull().toList()),
```