# Flutter arrayUnion: The getter 'iterator' was called on null

Tags: arrays, flutter, firebase, dart, null

I have a `List<String>` (uploadedFileUrls1) and `String` (uploadedFileUrl2) that I am adding to an array in Firebase. Each can be populated, one null, or both null. It seems to work if both are populated, or if just the loadedFileUrls1 is populated (uploadedFileUrl2 is `null`). However, if uploadedFileUrls1 (`List<String>`) is null, I am getting this error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy to check if this value is null or not. If it is null, I do not want to write anything to Firebase. Any suggestions?

Comment: "there doesn't seem to be an easy to check if this value is null or not.". Why not? This should be easy and straighforward

Comment: You can just check in the if condition. if (uploadedFileUrls1 != null && uploadedFileUrls1.isNotEmpty) {}

Comment: @ChiragKalsariya thanks for the reply. I should have supplied more context to my problem. I need to check each independently while also having the ability to update none, one, or both in the Firebase array. I am still struggling on how to do all of these operations at once. Here the is the problem with a bit more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586476/flutter-check-if-multiple-strings-are-empty-or-null-while-adding-to-array/72586583?noredirect=1#comment128248680_72586583